# When I click on materialize carousel image, the carousel rotates instead of opening the link

Tags: carousel, materialize

I have two materialize carousels side by side on my projects page. On my desktop I click the image and the carousel scrolls instead of opening the link. I know the link is active because if I right click on the image it and click open in new window, the desired page loads in a new window. The same thing happens on mobile but I don't have to right click I just have to hold my thumb down for 2 seconds.

I would like to have it so it does not scroll on click, but only on click and drag. Also would like the link to work with just a tap on mobile.

I've tried adding more rows, changing the size of the titles, changing min-height of the carousel, using z-index.

Here is a link to the site: https://vellios-professional-portfolio.herokuapp.com/projects.html

Here is a link to the full repo: https://github.com/TheGreekCuban/Alexander-Vellios-Portfolio

UPDATE: I've noticed that the clicking works properly if I click the image to the LEFT of the image in focus. But obviously I don't expect the user to click around until they figure this out. I need it to work on the image in focus.

Carousel html:

```
<div class= "carousel" id="fs">
        <h4>Full Stack Applications</h4>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="https://bleauwonder.github.io/renegades-of-silicon-alley/"><img src="../img/compass.jpg" class="responsive-img">
            <h6 class= "carouselTitle white-text">Renegade TrailBrews</h6>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="https://shrouded-brushlands-82538.herokuapp.com/"><img src="../img/weardrobedb.png" class="responsive-img">
            <h6 class= "carouselTitle white-text">WeardrobeDB</h6>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="https://burgerbar-alexander.herokuapp.com/"><img src="https://i.gifer.com/IaCK.gif" class="responsive-img">
            <h6 class= "carouselTitle white-text">Burger Bar</h6>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="https://scrape-oholic.herokuapp.com/"><img src="../img/scrape.gif" class="responsive-img">
            <h6 class= "carouselTitle white-text">The Real News Scraper</h6>
        </a>
    </div>


    <div class="carousel" id="mp">
        <h4>Mini-Projects (Desktop Only)</h4>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="https://thegreekcuban.github.io/Star-Wars-RPG/"><img src="../img/SW.jpg">
            <h6 class= "carouselTitle white-text">Star Wars RPG</h6>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="https://thegreekcuban.github.io/TriviaGame/"><img src="../img/got.jpeg">
            <h6 class= "carouselTitle white-text">GOT Trivia</h6>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="https://thegreekcuban.github.io/Hangman/"><img src="../img/Hangman_game.gif">
            <h6 class= "carouselTitle white-text">Word Guess Game</h6>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="https://thegreekcuban.github.io/API-Homework/"><img src="../img/travel.gif">
            <h6 class= "carouselTitle white-text">Gif Generator</h6>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="https://thegreekcuban.github.io/Train-Scheduler-App/"><img src="../img/train.gif">
            <h6 class= "carouselTitle white-text">Train Scheduler</h6>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="https://thegreekcuban.github.io/liri-node-app/"><img src="../img/liri.png">
            <h6 class= "carouselTitle white-text">Liri Node App</h6>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="https://thegreekcuban.github.io/Bamazon/"><img src="../img/bamazon.gif">
            <h6 class= "carouselTitle white-text">Bamazon Node Store</h6>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="https://alexander-friend-finder.herokuapp.com/"><img src="../img/facebook.png" class="responsive-img">
            <h6 class= "carouselTitle white-text">GOT Friend Finder</h6>
        </a>
</div>
```

Carousel Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      indicators: true
    });
  });
```

Carousel CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template:  "nav nav nav nav"
                    "fs fs mp mp"
                    "fs fs mp mp"
                    "fs fs mp mp"
                    "footer footer footer footer";
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, minmax(auto, 1fr));
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    background-color: #3A3A3A;
}

#navContainer {
    margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
}

#fs {
    grid-area: fs;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#mp {
    grid-area: mp;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

nav {
    background-color: #107C10;
    color: #3A3A3A;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #3A3A3A;
    grid-area: nav;
}

#footer {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
    background-color: #107C10;
    color: #3A3A3A;
    border-top: 3px solid #3A3A3A;
    grid-area: footer;
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

There are no errors, I just want a simple click to open the underlying link instead of a scroll. I am using google chrome if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a time loop function and call carousel to go to the next slide:

```js
const elems = document.querySelector('.carousel');
const duration = 3000; //milliseconds 

// Init
M.Carousel.init(elems); 

// Time loop function
setInterval(function () {
  M.Carousel.getInstance(elems).next(); // See Materialize Documentation for next
}, duration);
```